# crontab output nothing when calling a .sh that contains an output

Tags: linux, shell, output, cron

I have the following `test.sh` file in `/home/me` folder

```
#!/bin/sh
_now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
_file="/home/me/$_now.txt"
speedtest-cli --simple > $_file
```

Where `speedtest-cli` is a python script that gives internet up and dll speed infos : https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli.

Calling `test.sh` from `/home/me` works very good: I get my `yyy_mm_dd.txt` output with all infos (dll speed up speed, etc.).

But when I try to call the `test.sh` from a crontab I get a empty `yyy_mm_dd.txt` file (nothing inside).

Inside `crontab-e`

```
20 20 * * *  /home/me/test.sh
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think you did something wrong: It looks like you didn't check stderr from your cron job ;-)  A cron job runs in a environment which is different from when you run a script from your login shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect a PATH problem, so

pick one of :

- add `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` in the top of your script
- add in the top of `crontab -e` : `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` on his own line
- `source ~/.bashrc` in the top of your script
- add full path to each commands in your script

Comment: Isn't it `~/.bashrc`? [with a dot]

Comment: Thanks Gilles it works fine. I chose the first option:  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

Your `PATH` is probably different for your interactive shell than the context your cronjob runs in, so you should specify the full path of `speedtest-cli` in your crontab entry.